# How to create a trigger updating 2 tables in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables (in MySQL):

sales(sale_id, customer_id, sale_date, dicount, stock_item_id, seller_id, quantity)

record example:

```
a0018 | m9795 | 2017-10-2020 | 5    | MarFT | 0 | B-77028
```

stock(stock_item_id,supplier_name,supplier_email,supplier_phone,item_category   item_name,wholesale_price,markup_price,items_in_stock)

record example:

```
B-77001 |BSN |direct@bsn.com | 1877333665 | Gainers | True Mass | 2.6kg | 33.75 |44.99 | 500
```

I need to create a trigger that will add a new record into sales table (recording a new sale, that will autoincrement). At the same time I want stock table to update 'items_in_stock' value (that should decrease by whatver quantity was just sold when there is match on stock_item_id)? I hope this makes sense. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Keep in mind this is not *please write my code for me* site. Please take a tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour and also read on how to as questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and then edit your question and provide us with more information, ie what did you try so far? Did you made any research? What is the exact problem you have?

Comment: what have you tried so far? did you encounter an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    TRIGGER `OnSalesInsert` BEFORE INSERT ON `Sales` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

       UPDATE Stock 
       SET items_in_stock = items_in_stock - new.quantity 
       WHERE stock_item_id = new.stock_item_id; 

    END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Hi Abhishek. Thanks for this so far. Just run the above and got: "0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1449 The user specified as a definer ('root'@'%') does not exist". Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: run it without that line

Comment: **need to create a trigger that will add a new record into sales table** which event will trigger the trigger?

Comment: Event of making sale (adding a new record in 'sales' table) triggers the decrease of 'items_in_stock' in stock table. So let say someone buys an item with  stock_item_id of B-77001 such an event will be created in sales table (new sale_id, etc) - let's assume that customer bought 30 of stock_item_id B-77001. What should happen then is that 'items_in_stock' in stock table for stock_item_id B-77001 should decrease by 30.

Comment: updated my code, when you will insert in `Sales`; `Stock` table will be updated.

Comment: Great stuff. Thanks for your help!

Comment: my pleasure:) !!